# Странная ошибка Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Всем привет, столкнулся с непонятной ситуацией. Пробую через codefirst создать БД, потом вручную добавляю ее в проект, и вручную заполняю. Однако после запуска проекта, даже без внесения новых строк данных в коде БД больше не работает. Если через обозреватель серверов попробовать обратиться к БД и обновить данные в ней то вылазит ошибка, см. скрин1, если попытаться добавить данные в таблицу, то другая ошибка, см. скрин2. Ума не приложу, что случилось. Выкладываю код

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
class Player
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
class DB : DbContext
{
    public DB() : base("db") { }
    public DbSet<Player> Players { get; set; }
}
class Demo
{
    static void Main()
    {
        DB db = new DB();
        db.Players.Add(new Player() { Name = "I am" });
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Строку подключения создал до запуска приложения, чтобы потом добавить БД по ней

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="db" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\lab\data.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

[image: Скрин1]

[image: Скрин2]

Comment: Не мучайся, создай сначала базу, а потом сгенерируй С# классы через CodeFirst from DB.

Comment: попробуйте в качестве провайдера указать "(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB" вместо "(LocalDB)\v11.0"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Работа над ошибками:

```
    public partial class DBModel : DbContext
    {
        public DBModel()
        : base("name=DBModelSettings")
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Player> Players { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
        }
    }

    [Table("Player")]
    public partial class Player
    {
       public int Id { get; set; }

       [Required]
       [StringLength(255)]
       public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```